# Ajax call as async

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

Hi i am using ajax first time

my i am using get method in Ajax

my code Ajax code is

```
$("#comboBox1").change(function() {
        var text2 = $(this).children(':selected').text();
        var value2 = $(this).val();
        alert(text2 + " = " + value2);
        document.getElementById("hid1").value = value2;

                    $.get('Check1',{hid1:value2},function(res){
             $('#block3').load("new1.jsp");
                    });

                    if($('#cb5').length){
            alert("Found");
            combo2=$('#cb5').html();
            alert(combo2);
        }else{
            alert("Not-found");
        }
});
```

i need to call as asynchronous so where to put `async:true` in my code.

I am first time use Ajax so i Dose not know....
if anyone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async:true` is default in jQuery framework

If you want manage by `$.ajaxSetup()` function, because `$.get` dose not provide the pass additional setting params,

`$.ajax()` will be better and more intuitive

OR

`$.ajaxSetup({async:true});` to setup globally

Comment: but i does not have enough knowledge of Ajax...
i am only learn $.get() method from internet....
i am trying call using $.ajax()
but can't run...

Comment: if you are convert my $.get() function to $.ajax() so it would be more helpful to me...:)

Answer (score 0):

The "load" function you are using is already performing an (asynchronous) Ajax call. You do not have to add anything. It is asynchronous by itself.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) for some more information.

To execute code after the function returns you can use

```
    $('#block3').load("new1.jsp",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("Found");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
```

Comment: i have some line of code in my script tag after Ajax code
so when i am run program before Ajax lode other lines are execute...
so i want to control that line after success load Ajax other code is Execute...